# R: Assigning variable names based on imported filenames

Tags: r

I have a list of filenames that were found by searching the working directory. I want to either make one data frame with multiple elements that can be selected from or multiple data frames. To select either parts of one data frame or pick from multiple data frames, I want to name them using a part of the associated filename.

Currently, I set `filenames` using `list.files` and set up the data frame using `lapply` with `read.csv`

```
filenames = list.files(recursive=TRUE,pattern="*dat.csv",full.names=FALSE)
data = lapply(filenames,function(i){
  read.csv(i,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
```

Can someone explain to me the best way to go about this data import and name assignment?

Comment: If you run `data = Map(function(i{read.csv(i,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}, filenames)`, you'll get a named list of vectors. is this all you need? Can you be more precise on what exactly the desired output is?

Comment: I would like to remove portions of the filenames before assigning them to parts of data. What you suggested works, but makes calling the data more complicated than I am trying to do. For example, I want to assign file1 to a vector, but using your suggestion, the vector is instead named 'folder/file1.csv'. It seems like I need to assign the vector names after they have been imported with read.csv. Unless you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to store this would be as a single, combined data frame with a column describing the original file, let's say `type`:

```
data_frames = lapply(filenames,function(i){
    ret <- read.csv(i,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    ret$type <- gsub("dat.csv$", "", i)
    ret
})
data = do.call(rbind, data_frames)
```

Or shorter, with plyr:

```
library(plyr)
data = ldply(filenames, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, .id = "type")
data$type <- gsub("dat.csv$", "", data$type)
```

That way you could extract whatever subset you wanted with:

```
# to get all lines from, say, the AAAdat.csv file
subset(data, type == "AAA")
```

You *could* store each dataset as an individual variable with a name like `AAA`, but you shouldn't, because [it's a bad idea to use your variable names to store information](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

(Note that this assumes your datasets share most, or at least some, columns. If they have entirely different structures, this is not an appropriate approach).

Comment: This method seems to make it more difficult for me to handle the data when each data file isn't placed into its own vector. I would have an easier time just knowing the filename order and calling the corresponding data with data[1] or whichever one I am looking for.

Comment: @Eric You could do that with `data = lapply(filenames, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. But I really do recommend the "as a combined data frame" approach. When combined with tools such as dplyr, ggplot2, and the general [tidy data framework](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper), you can do much more powerful things. (For example, performing an operation on all your datasets at the same time is easy, as is plotting them all in subplots of the same graph)

Comment: Say I want to have subset "AAA", "BBB", and "CCC" all plotted in one plot. The data I have is 20 columns (plus a 21st type column that your solution added). I want to plot the 1st and 7th columns for each different subset. One this plot, I want each subset to have a different point type or line type depending on the specific plot I am constructing. Previously I have used a for loop that looks like `j=1for (i in c("AAA","BBB","CCC")){points(data[[i]][,1],data[[i]][,7],pch=j,lwd=2) j=j+1}`. This was for a vector where each dataset could be called with `data[[1]][,1]`.